# How to use one-liner if without else statement in .map() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I have an issue which I do not how to resolve.

I want to map data with `.map((x) => x.data)` with one-liner if statement inside, but without any else statement. I would like to achieve more or else 'pass' just as in Python.

In example:

What I want:

```
let mappedData = data.map((x) => x.data === filters.data ? [x.value, x.name, x.category]: pass);
```

This should return `mappedData` with data that only fill the condition.

When I use sth like this

```
let mappedData = data.map((x) => x.data === filters.data ? [x.value, x.name, x.category]: {});
```

It returns array of size data and with empty dicts if condition is not filled.

I tried as well sth like this:

```
let mappedData = data.map((x) => x.data === filters.data && [x.value, x.name, x.category]);
```

But that gives me `false` at each index that does not fill the condition.

I really would like to do one-liner if possible.

Thanks guys

Comment: Split it out into a call to `filter` with the condition chained with a `map`

Comment: Usually you'll perform a `.filter()` first then perform your `.map()` operation. Otherwise if you want to do it in the one pass, you can use `.flatMap()` and map to an empty array when you want to pass (not really recommended), or use `.reduce()` (or use a plain for loop, but that will look strange as a one-liner)

Comment: Thank guys,

What about doing `.filter(Boolean)` after mapping?

I would like to achieve as best performance as possible, would it be better to filter it before or after mapping?

Comment: @JustPawel mapping will always give you an array of the same length as the array you were originally mapping, so if your `data` has a length of N, then mapping will produce an array of size N, so if you put the filter after the map, the filter would need to do N iterations. If you do the filter first, that will need to do N iterations on your `data` originally but will produce a potentially smaller array size of length `M`, so the map would need to do M iterations in this case, which may be smaller than N (the length of data). So putting the filter first would be more optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't omit elements with a `map` call, but you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that, and then `map` the remaining elements:

```js
let mappedData =
   data.filter((x) => x.data === filters.data)
       .map((x) => [x.value, x.name, x.category]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you want, but will this help?

```js
let data = [{name: "Peter", age:29}, {name: "Rina", age: 36}, {name: "Joseph", age: 37}];
let filters = {name: "Rina", age: 36}; 
let res=[];
data.map((item) => {(item.name === filters.name)? res.push(item):null});
console.log(res);
```

```html
let mappedData = data.map((x) => x.data === filters.data ? [x.value, x.name, x.category]: pass);
```

Comment: The `.map()` method shouldn't be used if you're not using the array it returns. Instead, `.forEach()` is a better option, as that's designed for doing just iteration.